# What happens if I cast Green Sun's Zenith while Grafdigger's Cage is on the battlefield?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Grafdigger's Cage doesn't prevent me from casting Green Sun's Zenith from my hand, but what happens if I do?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two important comp. rules here:

> **101.2.** When a rule or effect allows or directs something to happen, and another effect states that it can't happen, the "can't" effect takes precedence.
>
> **609.3.** If an effect attempts to do something impossible, it does only as much as possible.

So you'll search your library for a green creature cost with converted mana cost X or less, **do absolutely nothing with it** (since you cannot, due to Grafdigger's Cage) and leave it in your library, then shuffle your library, then shuffle Green Sun's Zenith into it's owner's library.

This allows you to shuffle Green Sun's Zenith into your library for G, which might be handy/relevant in some obscure case (possibly against mill decks?).

Comment: It is also important if someone somehow flashes in a Grafdigger's Cage while GSZ is on the stack.

Comment: So, do you still get the creature into your hand, you just have to play it again?

Comment: @DForck42 no, there's no effect that allows you to put the creature from your library into your hand. You get to search your library for a creature and do nothing with it.

Comment: OK, so the creature just gets dumped into the graveyard.  You might add that for clarity (because it wasn't clear to me)

Comment: @DForck42, I don't think the creature goes into the graveyard, because it isn't countered. I think it just gets shuffled into the library with the Zenith.

Comment: @DForck42 Nope - there's no effect that allows you put the creature into the graveyard, either.  The creature does not change zones - you get to find a creature in your library and literally do nothing with it, leaving it in your library when you shuffle it.

Comment: @IanPugsley oh....  yeah you definitely need to add that little detail, please

Comment: Shuffling your deck is also useful if you know what the top card is and don't want to draw it (because you think you can get something better)